# Create react app is not working with proxy set

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a new React application with create-react-app. If the proxy is set in npmrc file, it is giving `E504 unknown host`.

If the proxy is removed, it is taking a lot of time? Maybe it is stuck?

```
Creating a new React app in E:\react\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

[ .................] - fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule js-tokens@4.0.0 checking installable status
```

Comment: try npm cache clean --force and create-react-app my-apps again.

Comment: tried the same still getting the same error